# How does fontset work in emacs?

Tags: emacs, character-encoding, fonts

I read some documentation about font configuration in Emacs, I found two concept, which are`FONT` and `FONTSET`. Currently, my understanding is that, `fontset` is a set of `font` which are grouped by the `script`( aka encoding ), and we can create a fontset and specify some set of chars to use specific font.

But until now, some experiments code does not always work as I wish, so I want to find what's the problem is?

First, I create my own fontset

```
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
 "-outline-Cousine-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-fontset-Consolas")
```

Then I want to use it as current emacs fontset( or is this possible? I am not sure), the following code seems works:

```
(set-frame-font "fontset-Consolas" nil t)
```

Then I try to customize my fontset for some specific character or encoding:

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-Consolas" 'han "Microsoft YaHei" nil 'prepend)
```

However, it's pity that this does not work, and the char in `'han` category do not change its font. Then I got some sample code and try the following one:

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-Default" 'han "Microsoft YaHei" nil 'prepend)
```

This time, it works, the char in 'han category use the correct font. But why i need to change `fontset-default` instead of my `fontset-consolas`.
Then I try to revert my change, with following code:

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-Default" 'han "Consolas" nil 'prepend)
```

However, the `'han` category char remains the same, which I expect these char should not display correctly, as I use a font does not contains those char. Why does changing `fontset-default` not work this time?

Besides the code above,  some more universal question:

1. How to change the emacs default fontset to my own one, is it possible?
2. Is multi fontset works at the same time or only one fontset work? Why my test code need to change `default` instead of mine?
3. The `set-fontset-font` second parameter is `target`, how can I know which script name is suitable for the char under current cursor. I can use `describe-char` to display the char information, but I don't find which word in this description is the correct one for that `target` param.
4. Some points worthy of notice for font configuration in emacs?

My question is kind of lengthy, so thanks for your patient and share your suggestion.

Comment: This is a good question, but apparently very few people are familiar with Emacs fontsets. That your customization of `fontset-Consolas` does not have effect might be the result of an Emacs bug. I recommend that you mail a reduced variant of the question (only the part pertaining to `set-fontset-font` apparently not working for user-created fontsets) to `bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org`.